# How to amend a new key to existing object using session storage

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have below piece of code

```
addToFilterCriteriaTree(componentData) {
        let id = componentData.props.data.id;
        this.state.filterCriteriaTree[id] = componentData.criteria; 
}
```

Instead of state ,I want to create a object 'filterCriteriaTree' using setStorage and add a new key to it

Comment: you can re-initialize the variable with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the parameters since it's cleaner to supply only the data needed for the function to do it's job rather than the entire object.

```
addToFilterCriteriaTree(id, criteria) {
  let currentFilterCriteriaTree = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterCriteriaTree')) || {};
  currentFilterCriteriaTree[id] = criteria;
  sessionStorage.setItem('filterCriteriaTree', JSON.stringify(currentFilterCriteriaTree);
}
```